# Problem with HTML 5 video, the video is not playing

Tags: wordpress, video, incognito-mode, playing

I used this code but it only Run on Incognito.
video playing proper in private browser but not playing in chrome, mozila. how it can be solved please help me i tired in 8 days

```html
<video controls muted>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
```

Comment: Above snippet works fine for me (safari on Mac, Chrome on Mac) - can you give a little more detail on the problems you are seeing when you try it on your browser.

Comment: yes sure once i upload a course video in my wordpress website and video size is 200MB to 600MB.once upload successfully then i refresh my page and video is visible but video take continue load not playing once i hard refresh then play otherwise only buffing.i m tired to solve this problem.i hope you help me today

Comment: Can you share a link to the website if possible as that will make I easier for people to help you?